# Would be a question about a particular free on-line class be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I'm an experienced programmer. Now I'm venturing into Big Data domain where my knowledge is extremely limited.

I would like to take a course on a particular subject in this area.  I have already found one and it seems OK to me, though there are others of course.

Would it be appropriate to ask the following questions on this site:

1. Has someone taken XYZ course from ABC company?  If so, could you please share your experience?
2. What other classes that your personally took would you recommend to others and why?

I understand that at least some of the answers will be extremely subjective ("*Like - Don't like*" perspective).  Is it a big NO here or can it be tolerated as long as I'm not asking general questions about the best training ever but keep it focused on much narrower topic?

Answer (score 3):

These types of questions are not allowed. They fall into a few categories that are off-topic on the site, such as being product/service recommendations and career/education advice. It also falls into several categories identified as being too subjective such that every answer is equally valid and there's no actual problem being solved.